# How do i check if data in a text file is missing, a delimiter is missing or the data format is invalid and display to the user what is wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, validation

I have some java code in which i am trying to check if data in a text file is there and in the correct format and display it to the user.

Code i have is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int itemcount = 0;
String line;
String input;
int i = 0;
String[] title = new String[20];
String[] author = new String[20];
String[] publisher = new String[20];
float[] price = new float[20];
int[] pages = new int[20];
String[] ISBN = new String[20];
int x = 0;


while (i == 0)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the file name (with .txt):");
    input = scan.nextLine();
    File Fileobject = new File (input);
    try {
        Scanner FileReader = new Scanner (Fileobject);
        //FileReader.useDelimiter(" - ");

        // Read and display each line in the file
        while(FileReader.hasNextLine())
            {
            line = FileReader.nextLine();
            Scanner LineReader = new Scanner(line);
            LineReader.useDelimiter(" - ");
            //System.out.println(line);
            title[x] = LineReader.next();//STORES ALL ITEMS IN ARRAY
            author[x] = LineReader.next();
            publisher[x] = LineReader.next();
            price[x] = LineReader.nextFloat(); 
            pages[x] = LineReader.nextInt();
            ISBN[x] = LineReader.next();
            //System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.print(String.format("%-15s", "Title:"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s", title[x]));
            System.out.print(String.format("%-15s", "Author:"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s", author[x]));
            System.out.print(String.format("%-15s", "Publisher:"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s", publisher[x]));
            System.out.print(String.format("%-15s", "Price:"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s", price[x]));
            System.out.print(String.format("%-15s", "Pages:"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s", pages[x]));
            System.out.print(String.format("%-15s", "ISBN:"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s", ISBN[x]));
            //System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            i++;
            x++;
            }

        FileReader.close();
        }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        System.out.println("File not found, please check and re-enter the name.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Data is taken from the text file and then stored in arrays, from there it is then printed out to the user.

A typical output i have is:

Title:         OOP programming
Author:        Graham Winter
Publisher:     O'Reilly
Price:         32.5
Pages:         120
ISBN:          0471974555

Title:         CCDA Exam Guide
Author:        Anthony Bruno
Publisher:     Cisco Press
Price:         49.95
Pages:         232
ISBN:          0735700745

Title:         Guide to Networks
Author:        Tamara Dean
Publisher:     Course Tech
Price:         34.5
Pages:         64
ISBN:          1439055661

Title:         Wireless Hacks 
Author:        Rob Weeks
Publisher:     O'Reilly
Price:         29.5
Pages:         890
ISBN:          0596101442

Title:         Large Scale LANs
Author:        Kevin Dooley
Publisher:     O'Reilly
Price:         39.0
Pages:         98
ISBN:          0596001509

Title:         Learning Java
Author:        William Lane
Publisher:     Wiley
Price:         12.0
Pages:         158
ISBN:          0072263445X

I am wanting to check the following and output the error to the user:

**Check if the book title is missing**

**Check if the author is missing**

**Check if the publisher is missing**

**Check if isbn is missing**

**Check if the delimiter is missing or wrong**

**Check if pages is numeric**

**Check if price is numeric**

Example of data in text file:

```
Learning Java - William Lane - Wiley - 12.00 - 158 - 0072263445X
- William Stalling -  Prentice Hall - 25.00 - 120 -  1304086641
OOP programming - Graham Winter - 32.50 - O'Reilly - 0471974555
Windows XP Unwired - Wei Meng Lee - 24.95 - O'Reilly - 0596005369
```

Order should be: Title - Author - Publisher - Price - Pages - ISBN.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried adding try,catch statements to each section where data is added to arrays to try and catch InputMismatchExeptions. My program seems to take the literal of the file and appends spaces to the arrays.

This does not work either. I understand the code is probably taking the literal of the file data. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started with adding the validation? Im not asking for it doing for me just need some guidance.

Comment: You need severe code and question formatting and management

Comment: Hi Branden, could you please use code blocks for your examples? Can you also add some code snippets to show us where are you stuck? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use String.isEmpty() to figure out if the something like the booktitle or author is missing. It gives back a boolean and checks if the string is empty or null.

For instance:

```
String line = LineReader.next();
if(!line.isEmpty()) {
    title[x] = line;
}
```

More info and examples are found here: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-isempty

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way I am aware of is to initialize all the variables to `0`. Do for loop for all the arrays and check if the `0` has been changed, if not return `false` else return `true` for every element that has not been changed.

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){ 
     if(title[i].equals(0))
        System.out.println("Empty Title");
}
```

and so on.